# Positioning div and span text inside it

Tags: html, css

I have tried a lot things but not able to get desired format.
HTML:

```
<div class="usertype">
            <div class="type1">
              <span class="type-heading">type1 is here</span>
              <span class="type-description">10 types have joined</span>
              <span class="type-description">35 type will.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="type2">
              <span class="type-heading">type2 is here</span>
              <span class="type-description">10 types are there</span>
              <span class="type-description">35 type will.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="type1">
              <span class="type-heading">type23 is good</span>
              <span class="type-description">50 types are there</span>
              <span class="type-description">50 types are there</span>
              <span class="type-description">for 2 months</span>
            </div>
            <div class="type2">
              <span class="type-heading">Type4 at last</span>
              <span class="type-description">50 types are there</span>
              <span class="type-description">makes their first $20</span>
              <span class="type-description">50 types are there</span>
              <span class="type-description">35 type will.</span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.usertype {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
div.type1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
span.type-heading {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #f7f7f7;
}

span.type-description {
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#959595;
  display: block;
}
```

Output:
[image: Output]

What I want:

1. Decrease the vertical distance between spans with class `type-description`. I tried using `line-height` and `padding-bottom` but could not move it. May be some parent div has `display:block`.
2. All type description aligned to left which are now center. If I use it `float: left`, it ruins the format completely.

Please help.

Comment: Seems like you've left some CSS out. Reproducing this doesn't yield the example image you posted.

Comment: You mean something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/WfdLN/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="usertype">
<div class="type1">
<span class="type-heading">type1 is here</span>
<span class="type-description">10 types have joined</span>
<span class="type-description">35 type will.</span>
</div>
<div class="type2">
<span class="type-heading">type2 is here</span>
<span class="type-description">10 types are there</span>
<span class="type-description">35 type will.</span>
</div>
<div class="type1">
<span class="type-heading">type23 is good</span>
<span class="type-description">50 types are there</span>
<span class="type-description">50 types are there</span>
<span class="type-description">for 2 months</span>
</div>
<div class="type2">
<span class="type-heading">Type4 at last</span>
<span class="type-description">50 types are there</span>
<span class="type-description">makes their first $20</span>
<span class="type-description">50 types are there</span>
<span class="type-description">35 type will.</span>
</div>
</div>

<style>

div.usertype {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
div.type1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
div.type2 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
span.type-heading {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #f7f7f7;
}

span.type-description {
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#959595;
  display: block;
  line-height:15px;
}
</style>
```